# scala two variables if else condition

Tags: scala, if-statement, switch-statement, case

How can I do this better in Scala?

```
def fooOutput(v1: Double, v2: Int): Int = {
    if (v1 >= 9 & v2 >= 2) {
      5
    }

    else if (v1 >= 8) {
      4
    }
    else if (v1 >= 4) {
      3
    }
    else {
      2
    }
  }
```

I do not like this if else if else logic.

Can I use switch statement for two variables or maybe some better Scala functional approach?

Comment: What don't you like in this code?

Comment: You can remove the braces to make it shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You can move your condition into pattern guards, not sure that it will be much better though:

```scala
def fooOutput(v1: Double, v2: Int): Int = v1 match {
  case _ if v1 >= 9 && v2 >= 2 => 5
  case _ if v1 >= 8            => 4
  case _ if v1 >= 4            => 3
  case _                       => 2
}
```